# React Native drawer navigation: how to open drawer by clicking custom button in specific scene?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

I've tried to open the drawer by clicking the following button (screenshot) in a specific scene.
[current status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llqcy.png)

and here goes my code.

```
// App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer'
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen'
import RNBootSplash from "react-native-bootsplash"

import MainCategory from './src/Scenes/MainCategory'
import SubCategory from './src/Scenes/SubCategory'
import DetailScene from './src/Scenes/DetailScene'
import Questions from './src/Scenes/Questions'
import Ruleta from './src/Scenes/Ruleta'

import CustomDrawerComponent from './src/Components/CustomDrawerComponent'

export default class MainRouter extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
      SplashScreen.hide()
      RNBootSplash.hide({ duration: 250 })
  }
  render() {
    const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
      MainCategory: {screen: MainCategory},
      SubCategory: {screen: SubCategory},
      DetailScene: {screen: DetailScene},
      Questions: {screen: Questions},
      Ruleta: {screen: Ruleta},
    }, {
      initialRouteName: "MainCategory",
      headerMode: "none"
    })

    const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
      MainCategory: {screen: MainCategory},
    }, {
      drawerPosition: 'right',
      contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent
    })

    const MainNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
      Stack: StackNavigator,
      Drawer: DrawerNavigator,
    }, {
      initialRouteName: 'Stack',
      contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent
    })

    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigator)
    return(
      <AppContainer />
    )
  }
}
```

```
// Specific scene
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ScrollView, StatusBar, View, TouchableOpacity, Text, Image, Modal } from 'react-native'

import HeaderBar from '../Components/HeaderBar'

export default class Questions extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            headerTitle: props.navigation.getParam('headerTitle'),
            catId: props.navigation.getParam('catId'),
        }
    }

    openSideMenu = () => {
        this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer
        this.props.navigation.openDrawer()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={rootStyle}>
                <View>
                    <StatusBar hidden={false} translucent backgroundColor="transparent" barStyle="light-content" />
                    <HeaderBar title={headerTitle} onPressLeft={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()} leftShow={true} onPressRight={this.openSideMenu} rightShow={true} />
                </View>
                <ScrollView>
                    <QuestionList todoQues={todoQues} favQues={favQues} action={this.action.bind(this)} />
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

But it's not working.

I expect the result like the following screenshot.
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCBtl.png)

Please let me know what I should do more and how to use the drawer navigator in a specific scene.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: In my code, `this.props.navigation.openDrawer()` is not working.
If you know the reason, please let me know why it's not working.

Comment: any error you are getting , or simply its not working

Comment: I've fixed it but still has some bugs.
I imported the following code and it works now.
`import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation-drawer'`
...
`this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());`
For now, the drawer is opened but navigation is done before I click the drawer items in the drawer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all instead of calling the method **this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()**, call the method **this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())**.
You also need to import DrawerActions for this to work. And remove the first function that you called in your **openSideMenu** function because you don't need the **this.props.navigation.openDrawer()**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the code as you said and opendrawer is working now. My problem is when the drawer is opened, navigation is done automatically even though I don't click any items.

I've checked the code and tried by removing all `initialRouteName` options.
But still, auto navigation is done. (in this case, the route which is navigated is the first routing option in drawerNavigator. In above my code, Maincategory is done automatically.)

Comment: Remove your navigation methods (StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator, Switch Navigator) from your render method and put them outside it. 
Your code should look something like this:


`export default class AppNavigator extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}`

Comment: I've tried as you said, but there is still auto-navigation.
I'm going to post another question about this issue.
Thanks for your kind answer.